# cannot resolve symbol getCheckedRadioButtonId

Tags: android, android-radiogroup, android-radiobutton

I'm new in android and I have this problem in java code

```
cannot resolve symbol 'getCheckedRadioButtonId'
```

about this code

```
Bind(R.id.radioGroup) RadioGroup _radioGroup;

    if (_radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() != -1)
    {

    }
```

It does not receive `getCheckedRadioButtonId`. And I want to get the text from `RadioButton` checked. How do I do this ?

Comment: it returns the id of the selected radio button in this group so test will be like 
if (_radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() != R.id.myBox)

Comment: Are you using `ButterKnife` ?

Comment: Yes I use Butterknife

Comment: I can't understand please say more @OussemaAroua

Comment: the getCheckedRadioButtonId() returns the id of the radioButton inside the RadioGroup, you have to compare between the value returned by getCheckedRadioButtonId() and the RadioButtons ids

Comment: Can you post your app's `build.gradle` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37150435/6317485 @ShadabAnsari

Comment: It should be `@Bind` instead of `Bind`

Comment: I put @Bind  but I have the same erorr

Answer (score -1):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.elhez.tammeni"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.1.0'
}
```